# How to make flex value dynamic with Angular Material?

Tags: angular-material

I'm trying to implement a `<div>` with number of child `<div>` having dynamic flex value as per the number of child `<div>`.

Comment: Please let us know some more information - what have you tried, what is not working, how do you exactly want it to work? Its very hard for people to answer correctly if the question is vague. You should post some more information regarding the situation.

Comment: @Deepika :- This should work :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529966/how-to-implement-dynamic-flex-value-with-angular-material